# What exactly does once:true in the BrowserSync stream method?

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

According to the [BrowserSync docs](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/api) we can use the `stream()` method to inject our code into the browser. By adding `once:true` as a parameter we can make sure to do reloading only once per stream. But what does that mean concretely? So as far as I understood it makes sure that in case you add multiple source files the reload only occurs once. But then I found the following code:

```
gulp.task('js',function(){
  gulp.src('src/js/scripts.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream({ once:true }));
});
```

Why did they add the once parameter although only one file is processed?
 What does the `once:true` do exactly? What would happen if we removed it?

Comment: I think the code example you found just uses the once option incorrectly.  Probably no downside to it in their case.  I assume when there are multiple files in a stream browserSync must keep a record of whether stream() has been triggered and refuse to call the function again for that stream.  Where did you get that code example?

Comment: Ok thank you, I got it from here: https://github.com/HosseinKarami/fastshell